# Economics question. Rehashing the basics of dealing with exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, economics

Struggling to put two equations together effectively again.
I have my income equation:

$$
y=zk^\alpha
$$

And I'm trying to plug it into my marginal product of capital

$$
MPK=\alpha z k^{\alpha-1}
$$

I know the end product is

$$\alpha (zy^{\alpha -1})^\frac{1}{\alpha}
$$

But I can't see how to convert income into an effective equation to plug into my problem. I always end up with funny powers that don't seem to fit.

Thanks!

Comment: MPK is $$\frac{\partial y}{\partial k}=zk^\alpha $$ which equals $$\alpha zk^{\alpha -1} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $y=zk^\alpha$, so you can express $k$ in terms of $y$ as follows:-
$$k^\alpha=\left(\frac{y}{z}\right)\Rightarrow k= \left(\frac{y}{z}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}} $$
Substituting the value of $k$ into the $MPK$ results in:-
$$MPK=\alpha z k^{\alpha-1}=\alpha z\left(\frac{y}{z}\right)^{\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha}}=\alpha z^{(1-\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha})}y^{\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha}}=\alpha z^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}y^{\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha}}=\alpha (zy^{\alpha-1})^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}$$